# Partial class in MyClass.xaml not recognized by partial class in MyClass.xaml.cs

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind, partial-classes

I have a class, partially defined in XAML and partially in code:

The file *ElementResource.xaml* looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary  x:Class="TestElement.Views.ElementResource"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestElement.Views"
                     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestElement.ViewModels">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type vm:TestElementViewModel1}">
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The rest of the class *ElementResource" is defined in code in the file *ElementResource.xaml.cs* like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestElement.Views
{
    [Export(typeof(ResourceDictionary))]
    public partial class ElementResource : ResourceDictionary
    {
    }
}
```

For some reason, the class part defined in XAML is not recognized in the "code-behind":

[image: Not recognized]

Also, the DataTemplate defined in XAML is not contained in the resource dictionary after initialization.

I've tried building and rebuilding, *Ctrl+Shift+s* and double-checked the requirements for partial classes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221357%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#codebehind_and_partial_class_requirements).

What am I missing??

Comment: What purpose does the ExportAttribute server?

Comment: It's the Export attribute for dependency injection with MEF (MS Extensibility Frameworks). The export of the class works, just the XAML part is missing...

Comment: Gotcha, so that probably has nothing to do with your problem.  Probably a silly question but I have to ask. Your XAML and codebehind are in the same project?

Comment: Hehe, yes same folder, even..

Comment: Is everything with the DataTemplate in order? Visual Studio is able to resolve TestElementViewModel1 and whatever else might be in that XAML file? Maybe the XAML-defined portion or you partial class isn't compiling properly because of an unreported problem somewhere in the XAML.

Comment: almost... see below. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it: I copied and pasted the xaml file from another project and on pasting the file to the current project, it's **BuildAction** property changed to **none** which I didn't notice... Swithcing it to **Page** makes the xaml part known...

Thanks for your help, everybody!

Answer (score 1):

x:Class="TestElement.Views.ElementResource"

Is this your full assembly name? Try adding all parts, should be recognized then.

Comment: I know, it shouldn't be, but yes it is the full assembly name.

Answer (score 1):

In your XAML, are you missing "local:" in front of ResourceDictionary?

```
<local:ResourceDictionary  x:Class="TestElement.Views.ElementResource"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestElement.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestElement.ViewModels">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type vm:TestElementViewModel1}">
    </DataTemplate>

</local:ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: The *ResourceDictionary* is the base class of *ElementResource* (*System.Windows.ResourceDictionary*)... So, that doesn't work, unfortunately...

Comment: Oh, OK. Wasn't sure if that was another class you wrote in the TestElement.Views namespace.